# Allow other instances of files that is globally blocked in htaccess?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, htaccess

I am using the following command  inside `home/` to block all access to `wp_login.php`

```
<Files wp-login.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all    
</Files>
```

How can I allow certain instances of `wp_login.php` for example, allow:

`home/bob/public_html/wp_login.php`

and

`home/jim/public_html/wordpress/wp_login.php` ?

Comment: To all who are voting to migrate to webapps this isn't on-topic for them.  It's a valid question for here.

Answer (score 2):

You would need the appropriate `.htaccess` file in the new directories stating that the `wp-login.php` files in those are *allowed* access.

Apache will check the `.htaccess` file in the current directory, [then "backtrack"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#how) until it hits the `DocumentRoot`. The most relevant directive will apply, therefore a `deny` in `/home` and an `allow` in `/home/user/` will allow access to the instance in the user directory, while denying everywhere else under `/home`.

It does not seem possible to have all directives in the *same* `.htaccess` file; in that case, the `deny` rule seems to override the others (just tested on Apache 2.2.22).